# Вырезать кусок видео с помощью ffmpeg

Tags: ffmpeg

Надо оставить после действий видео БЕЗ промежутка. Не могу разобраться.

ffmpeg -i in.mp4 -ss 00:00:03 -t 00:00:08 -async 1 out.mp4
Вырезает кусок и оставляет только промежуток. Как и остальные действия с -ss. 
Что пропустил и не прочитал?

Comment: мне кажется, вот [здесь](http://superuser.com/a/863451/454489) дан исчерпывающий ответ на вопрос «как разрезать видеоролик на нужные куски и составить потом из них результирующий видеоролик».

Answer (score 2, accepted):

мне кажется, вот [здесь](https://superuser.com/a/863451/454489) дан исчерпывающий ответ на вопрос «как разрезать видеоролик на нужные куски и составить потом из них результирующий видеоролик».

в применении к вашему случаю:

```
$ ffmpeg -i in.mp4 -t 00:00:03 out1.mp4 -ss 00:00:11 out2.mp4
```

затем создайте файл с именем, например, `out.txt`, в котором перечислены получившиеся «куски»:

```
file 'out1.mp4'
file 'out2.mp4'
```

и «склейте» их вместе:

```
$ ffmpeg -f concat -i out.txt -c copy out.mp4
```

в дополнение информация с сайта разработчиков ffmpeg: https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Concatenate